# Multiply many columns by one column in dask

Tags: pandas, dask

I want to multiply roughly 50,000 columns with one other column in a large dask dataframe (`6_500_000 x 50_002`). The solution, using a for loop, works but is painfully slow. Below I tried two other appraoches that failed. Any advice is appreciated.

**Pandas**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})
df[['a','b']].multiply(df['c'], axis="index")
```

**Dask**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)

# works but very slow for large datasets: 
for column in ['a', 'b']:
    ddf[column] = ddf[column] * ddf['c']

# don't work:
ddf[['a','b']].multiply(ddf['c'], axis="index") 
ddf[['a', 'b']].map_partitions(pd.DataFrame.mul, other=ddf['c'] ).compute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.mul` for dask:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)

ddf[['a','b']] = ddf[['a','b']].mul(ddf['c'], axis='index') # or axis=0

ddf.compute()
Out[1]: 
    a   b  c
0   7  28  7
1  16  40  8
2  27  54  9
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically had it for pandas, just `multiply()` isn't inplace. I also changed to using `.loc` for all but one column so you don't type 50,000 column names :)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'c']=df.loc[:, df.columns != 'c'].multiply(df['c'], axis="index")
```

Output:

```
    a   b  c
0   7  28  7
1  16  40  8
2  27  54  9
```

NOTE: I am not familiar with Dask, but I imagine that it is the same issue for that attempt.